# Scroll to first invalid field with formik and useRefs react

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to adapt the code below to use react `useRef` as opposed to using `document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLElement;` as it's not the best practice in react. I'm trying to achieve functionality that scrolls to the first error on a Formik form, this code does work but how I can do this with React `useRef` instead?

here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik';

const FocusError = () => {
  const { errors, isSubmitting, isValidating } = useFormikContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSubmitting && !isValidating) {
      let keys = Object.keys(errors);
      if (keys.length > 0) {
        const selector = `[name=${keys[0]}]`;
        const errorElement = document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLElement;
        if (errorElement) {
          errorElement.focus();
        }
      }
    }
  }, [errors, isSubmitting, isValidating]);

  return null;
};

export default FocusError;

//Put it within formiks Form.

<Formik ...>
  <Form>
     ...
    <FocusError />
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 16):

There are already some good answers here, but I ended up taking a slightly different route that some might find appealing.

```
// in my ScrollToError.tsx file...
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export function ScrollToError() {
    const formik = useFormikContext();
    const submitting = formik?.isSubmitting;

    useEffect(() => {
        const el = document.querySelector('.Mui-error, [data-error]');
        (el?.parentElement ?? el)?.scrollIntoView();
    }, [submitting]);
    return null;
}

// later inside my <Formik/> component...
<ScrollToError/>
```

This finds the first .Mui-error element (typically the label for the field in question) and focuses its parent, or itself if no parent. In some cases, I add an `<Alert severity="error"/>` component to display a general error message, which this also finds if I tag it with the data-error attribute. The scroll only happens when `isSubmitting` changes.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of doing -

```
errorElement.focus();
```

Do this -

```
errorElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
errorElement.focus({ preventScroll: true });
```

Comment: This worked for me, but for 'errorElement' I needed to use 'querySelector' and then the parent. E.g.

```const el = document.querySelector('.is-invalid');
    el?.parentElement?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight update to 4nduril's answer.

This variation:

1. uses `focus` instead of only using `scrollIntoView` (better accessibility - see https://webaim.org/techniques/formvalidation/). Note that scrolling (including smooth scrolling) is still available in addition to setting focus.
2. uses `usePrevious` (https://ahooks.js.org/hooks/use-previous/) to only set focus to the invalid field *after* submitting has transitioned from true to false. This avoids the limitation where Formik's `validateOnBlur` has to be set to true in 4nduril's answer.
3. ensure the input *label* is always scrolled into view while the input itself is focused.

```
export const useFocusInvalidField = <
  T extends HTMLElement,
  U extends HTMLElement,
>(
  name: string,
  smoothScroll?: boolean,
) => {
  const formikContext = useFormikContext();
  // The input/select itself, this is what we will be focusing.
  const fieldRef = useRef<T>(null);
  // The container element that contains both the input/select and its label.
  // This is what we will be scrolling into view. Doing this helps guarantee that
  // the label will be visible. If the submit button is at the bottom of the form and the
  // label is above the invalid input, _just_ focusing the input could leave the
  // label offscreen (above the viewport) which can make it difficult for the user to
  // identify the invalid field.
  const containerElementRef = useRef<U>(null);

  const wasSubmitting = usePrevious(formikContext.isSubmitting);

  useEffect(() => {
    const firstError = Object.keys(formikContext.errors)[0];
    if (
      wasSubmitting === true &&
      !formikContext.isSubmitting &&
      firstError === name &&
      fieldRef.current !== null
    ) {
      // Use a helper function from https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-side-effects.
      // This does some browser compatibility and accessibility work for us.
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
      focusAndScrollIntoViewIfRequired(
        fieldRef.current, // focus the input/select
        containerElementRef.current ?? fieldRef.current, // scroll the container (and label) into view if set, otherwise scroll to the input
        smoothScroll, // optionally use smooth scroll. Accessibility note: this will ignore smooth scroll if the user has indicated a preference for reduced motion.
      );
    }
  }, [
    wasSubmitting,
    formikContext.isSubmitting,
    name,
    formikContext.errors,
    smoothScroll,
  ]);
  return { fieldRef, containerElementRef };
};
```

Comment: thanks for showing the approach. however, i have not been able to consistently scroll to the error field. sometimes the div is focused, sometimes it does not. 
here is a small codepen that shows it
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-v2-tutorial-final-forked-xitwqy?file=/src/index.js&resolutionWidth=430&resolutionHeight=470.

Comment: @Yuvi - I may be late to the party, but if you still have this issue, then you probably need to wire up the Select and the Checkbox with the above hook. Check this link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/formik-v2-tutorial-final-forked-3sytkx?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A37%2C36

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to build it into my custom form fields. I use MaterialUI TextFields but you can do it of course without. The relevant Code:

```js
import { TextField as MuiTextField } from '@material-ui/core'

export const TextField = ({ name, ...rest }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField({ name, type: 'text' })
  const formikBag = useFormikContext()
  const fieldRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const firstError = Object.keys(formikBag.errors)[0]
    if (formikBag.isSubmitting && firstError === name) {
      fieldRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' })
    }
  }, [meta.error, formikBag.isSubmitting, name, formikBag.errors])

  return (
    <MuiTextField
      id={field.name}
      ref={fieldRef}
      error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error)}
      helperText={meta.touched && meta.error}
      {...rest}
      {...field}
    />
  )
}
```

You can even extract it to a custom hook like this:

```js
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik'
import { useRef, useEffect, MutableRefObject } from 'react'

export const useScrollToInvalidField = <T extends HTMLElement>(name: string): MutableRefObject<T | null> => {
  const formikBag = useFormikContext()
  const fieldRef = useRef<T>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const firstError = Object.keys(formikBag.errors)[0]
    if (formikBag.isSubmitting && firstError === name) {
      fieldRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' })
    }
  }, [formikBag.isSubmitting, name, formikBag.errors])
  return fieldRef
}
```

Then you just give it the correct Element type of your field (e.g. `HTMLDivElement`) and attach the ref to the form field component.

Comment: This is nice, but it will only work if the order of your form inputs in the DOM matches the order of the Formik validation errors. This might be true sometimes but not always.

Comment: Another limitation I found here is that Formik's `validateOnBlur` must be set to true. If you have it set to false, you can trigger a situation where -- upon form submission -- a previously invalid field (that has since been fixed to be valid but Formik validation hasn't rerun yet) will still have focus moved to it.

Comment: I guess a third point I'd make is that for accessibility (and usability too I suppose) we should be moving _focus_ to the first invalid input, not just scrolling it into view.

Comment: Very good comments. I suggest anyone landing here to follow danielnixon's advice. Be sure to see their answer.

Answer (score 1):

i am using useFormik and made useEffect hook like this.

```
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues,
    validationSchema: validators,
    onSubmit: (values, {setErrors}) => {
      ....
    }
  });
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!formik.isSubmitting) return;
    if (Object.keys(formik.errors).length > 0) {
      document.getElementsByName(Object.keys(formik.errors)[0])[0].focus();
    }
  }, [formik]);
```

and it set focus to first invalid input field.
i hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

```
type ScrollToErrorsProps = {
  name?:                string;
  id?:                  string | any;
  formik?:              any;
};

export default class FocusError extends React.Component<ScrollToErrorsProps>{
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { name, id, formik } = this.props;
        if (this.props.formik.submitCount > 0 && this.props.formik.isValid === false) {
            if (Object.keys(this.props.formik.errors)[0] === this.props.name) {
                const el = document.getElementById(this.props.id);
        if (el) {
                  el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "nearest"});
        }
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).